# Como verificar se a latência do ip é maior que 0?

Tags: shell-script

Código:

```
 if [ 'ping $1 -c1 |grep rtt |awk {'print$4'} |awk -F "/" {'print$2'}' -gt 0 ]
    then
    echo "OK"
 else
    echo "NO OK"
 fi
```

Erro:

> ./latencia.sh: linha 1: [: ping $1 -c1 |grep rtt |awk {print} |awk -F
>   "/" {print}: esperado expressão de número inteiro NO OK

Comment: Se eu bem entendo o teu comando, estás a determinar o tempo médio do `ping` para determinada máquina. (1) não é de esperar tempos menores ou iguais a zero... (2) -gt faz comparação entre inteiros (3) a aspa em volta do comandi grande está trocada.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode comparar dois números do tipo float em bash usando o comando `bc`:

```
avg_rtt=$(ping $1 -c1 |grep rtt |awk {'print$4'} |awk -F "/" {'print$2'})

if (( $(echo "$avg_rtt > 0" |bc -l) )); then  
   echo "OK"
else
   echo "NO OK"
fi
```

Ainda assim, estás comparando com 0 (e aqui podes substituir por qualquer float), o que nunca é o esperado em um [round-trip time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time)(rtt) médio em um `ping`.

Answer (score 0):

Para obter os valores, você pode usar o comando:

```
ping $1 -c1 | cut -sd '/' -f5
```

Mas você continua não podendo fazer a comparação de um float com inteiro, além dos problemas que os outros usuários citaram.

Se quiser realmente comparar o valor com zero, você pode fazer dessa maneira:

```
# Salva o valor de retorno na váriavel $avg
avg=$(ping $1 -c1 | cut -sd '/' -f5)
# Converte a variável $avg para int e compara com zero
if [ ${avg%.*} -gt 0 ]; then
    # retorna OK caso seja maior que zero
    echo "OK"
else
    # retorna NO OK caso seja igual ou menor que zero
    echo "NO OK"
fi
```